# $exists query in mongodb c-api

Tags: c, mongodb, bson, mongodb-c

I am trying to implement the following mongodb query in C

`db.test.find({"timestamp": {"$exists":true}});`

I thought it would be something like

```
bson query, existspart;
mongo_cursor cursor;
int i;

bson_init(&existspart);
bson_append_string ( &existspart, "$exists", "false" );
bson_finish(&existspart);
bson_init(&query);
bson_append_bson ( &query, "timestamp", &existspart );
bson_finish(&query);    

mongo_cursor_init(&cursor, conn, "mydb.test");
mongo_cursor_set_query(&cursor, &query );
while( mongo_cursor_next( &cursor ) == MONGO_OK )
{
    // blabla
}
```

But it does not work. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
bson_append_string ( &existspart, "$exists", "false" );
```

with

```
bson_append_bool ( &existspart, "$exists", 1 );
```

or

```
bson_append_bool ( &existspart, "$exists", 0 );
```

if you do not want that field exist

Answer (score 0):

I used a slightly different syntax:

```
bson_t* existspart = BCON_NEW("$exists", BCON_BOOL(true));
bson_t *query = bson_new();
BSON_APPEND_DOCUMENT(query, "timestamp", existspart);

mongoc_cursor_t* cursor = MongoInterface::Instance().Find("db_name", query);

const bson_t *doc;
while (mongoc_cursor_next (cursor, &doc))
{
  // Do stuff...
}

bson_destroy (existspart);
bson_destroy (query);
```